# Identifying internal structure of dissected prawn

Tags: zoology, anatomy, organs, dissection, species-identification

**Note: Some of the images might be disturbing.**

I have dissected prawn for the first time. Would like your help in identifying some structures
.

1. This is the dissection of the posterior part of the prawn. What is this blackish structure in the middle ? This structure becomes whitish farther down. Then, it forms a small sac like structure and then becomes thin again. This whole structure appeared just after I cut the exoskeleton. It is directly above the muscles.

[image] 
[image]

[image]
[image]

I think that this is it's alimentary canal and the black area has digested food in it. The sac like structure might be the rectum.

Answer (score 2):

It is, indeed, the alimentary canal. It is actually this canal that it's important for one to remove when "de-veining" shrimp, rather than the vein itself, which lies immediately dorsal to the digestive tract.

---

In the future, I might suggest doing a little more research prior to asking the stack exchange, as frequent users of the site do like to see evidence of effort on the part of the user to find their own answers. A quick search for "alimentary canal prawn" or "arthropod anatomy" would likely have turned up your answer.